# How to compare two values at a specific location in a loop, and append data in a range of values in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a dataframe, from where I extracted some sample data:

```
    Time    Val
0   70000   -322
1   70500   -439
2   71000   -528
3   71500   -606
4   72000   -642
5   72500   -663
6   73000   -620
7   73500   -561
8   74000   -592
9   74500   -614
10  75000   -630
11  75500   -719
12  80000   -613
13  80500   -127
14  81000   -235
15  81500   -186
16  82000   -82
17  82500   836
18  83000   1137
183 70000   -106
184 70500   -117
185 71000   -626
186 71500   -810
187 72000   -822
188 72500   -676
189 73000   -639
190 73500   -664
191 74000   -708
192 74500   -515
193 75000   -61
194 75500   -121
195 80000   -145
196 80500   -57
197 81000   -133
198 81500   101
199 82000   235
200 82500   585
201 83000   550
366 70000   18
367 70500   138
368 71000   22
369 71500   -68
370 72000   -146
371 72500   -163
372 73000   -251
373 73500   -230
374 74000   -218
375 74500   -137
376 75000   -126
```

Now I would like to compare the value from 'Val' at time 73000 with the value [i-3].
If the value is less, then append the continuous values to the list until Time has reached 80000.
I wrote this loop but the problem is that 'Val' compares ALL values [i-3] between 73000 and 80000. I want that the comparison happens ONLY at 73000, and if the condition is true, write the  data to the list (until Time 80000)

```
box = []

for i in df.index:

    if df.Time[i] >= 73000 and df.Time[i] <= 80000 and df.Val[i] < df.Val[i-3]:

        box.append(
        {
            'Time': df.Time[i],
            'newVAL': df.Val[i],

        }
    )

box = pd.DataFrame (box, columns = ['Time','newVAL'])
```

How could I change the code in order to achieve this?

Comment: Several questions: 
1. What happens if there are multiple entries with date 73000?
2. Is the dataframe sorted by the "date" column or not?

Comment: Yes, value 73000 repeats. The loop should feed the list every time 73000 + condition true occurs and write the values from 'Val' to the list until time = 80000.

Comment: If Time = 73000 but Val [i] > Val [i-3], then don't append to the list and wait for the next cycle

Comment: Added an answer. Check if it helps.

Comment: It seems to give me the right results, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remember the result of the comparison in another variable, and reset it whenever you encounter a time value outside your desired interval. The code would look like this.

```
box = []

writeToList = False

for i in df.index:
    if df.Time[i] < 73000 or df.Time[i] > 80000:
        writeToList = False
    
    if df.Time[i] == 73000 and df.Val[i] < df.Val[i-3]:
        writeToList = True
    
    if writeToList and df.Time[i] >= 73000 and df.Time[i] <= 80000 :
        box.append(
        {
            'Time': df.Time[i],
            'newVAL': df.Val[i],
        }
    )

box = pd.DataFrame (box, columns = ['Time','newVAL'])
```

Hope this helps.